# How to get raw sql query string with all parameters escaped?

Tags: javascript, typeorm

```
console.log(
  myRepo
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .select('id')
    .andWhere('uuid = :uuid', { uuid: '170eb26c-19e7-418b-aae8-3308d61ef7d5' })
    .getSql()
);
```

prints:
`SELECT id FROM "my_entities" "MyEntity" WHERE uuid = $1`

How I can get query string with `$1` replaced to parameter value? Please note that I don't want to execute query - I just need query string without parameters.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is for MySql and if you are using Postgres it will slightly differ. 
You can use the underlying connection driver API to escape the parameters.

E.g.

```
import { MigrationInterface, QueryRunner } from 'typeorm';

export class SupplierLocations1582118993382 implements MigrationInterface {

    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<any> {

        const [query,parameters] = await queryRunner.connection.driver.escapeQueryWithParameters(
           'SELECT * from `supplier_locations` WHERE `supplierId` = :supplierId',
           {
                supplierId: supplier.SupplierEntity_id,
           },
           {}
        );

         const locationsRawResult = await queryRunner.query(query, parameters);

    }
    // async down migrations here
}

// The generated SQL
// ---------------------
// query: 'SELECT * FROM `supplier_locations` WHERE `supplierId` = ?'
// parameters: [1]
```

Note the empty braces is required according to the new API spec by TypeOrm, you can find more information about it here: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/556#issuecomment-556042689

Answer (score 2):

I found solution in this typeorm github issue: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/556#issuecomment-317459125:

```
async function rawQuery<T = any[]>(query: string, parameters: object = {}, manager?: EntityManager): Promise<T> {
  const conn = manager ? manager.connection : getConnection();
  const [ escapedQuery, escapedParams ] = conn.driver.escapeQueryWithParameters(query, parameters, {});
  return conn.query(escapedQuery, escapedParams);
}

// usage
const comments = await rawQuery<Array<{ id: number, comment: string }>>(
  'select id, comment from comments where post_id in (:...postIds)', { postIds: [1, 2, 3] }
);
```